# c++ vector of bitset pass to a function

Tags: c++, vector, bitset

I want to implement an algorithm in C++ that needs a dynamically assigned huge vector of bitset (512x18,000,000 bits - I have 16Gb of RAM).

a) This works fine

```
int nofBits=....(function read from db);
vector < bitset <nofBits> > flags;
flags.resize(512);
```

but how do I pass it (by reference) to a function? Keep in mind, I do not know nofBits in compile time.

I could use a

```
vector<vector<bool> >
```

but would not it be worse in terms of memory usage?

Comment: `do not know nofBits in compile time` then how on earth are you supposed to pass it to template?

Comment: If you know another way, please suggest one. No need to be harsh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had that same problem recently, however just like a std::array you need to know the size of the bitset at compile-time, since it's a template parameter. I found [boost::dynamic_bitset](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html) as an alternative, and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Thanks, just asking to be sure. It is either boost or vector<vector<bool> > for me. Right?

Comment: Yeah, as far as I know. I guess vector<vector<bool>> has the advantage that it doesn't require external libraries, while a boost::dynamc_bitset allows you to use bitwise operators such as |, &, ^, etc. I haven't tested them concerning memory usage, but I reckon they'd be about the same.

Comment: Thanks for the calrification. I am obliged

Answer (score 2):

`std::vector<bool>` is specialised to use memory efficiently. It is roughly as space efficient as `std::bitset<N>` (a few extra bytes because its size is dynamic and the bits live on the heap).

Note, however, that `std::vector<bool>` has [issues](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=98), so tread lightly.